# Afci's and Gfci's and motor loads

Tags: garage

Has anyone been reporting a problem with motor loads on Afci's or Gfci's in residential or commercial locations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be a common problem.

Unfortunately, equipment manufacturers fail to include simple devices to prevent nuisance tripping.  Hopefully either government regulations will require manufacturers to take action, or the AFCI/GFCI devices will get smart enough to recognize poorly built equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced many GFCI's on motor loads in homes most of the time garbage disposals and a few refrigerators / freezers. AFCI's constantly trip if a variable speed motor is controlling the speed OR a heavy lighting load with a dimmer. Most of the GFCI's used in industrial locations are not for personal protection but for protection of the equipment they have higher trip set-points if memory serves 30-100ma is there range where a GFCI for personal protection is 5ma +-1ma.